# Can we get JSON output with XSD schema in specified and required format?

Tags: json, xml, xsd, jsonp

I am trying to interface data from our system to third party system which accepts the data in standard json format and only in the specified format.Our systems delivers output in xml format where i would need xsd schema for transforming data from xml to json format.

following is the sample standard JSON format that third party system accepts

```
  {
  "checkups":
  [
  {
  "checkupId" : " 20 " ,
  "jobTitle": " Busisness Analyst, Project Management " ,
  "requisitionNumber": " F834234 " ,
  "subAccount":{
  "email": "ramesh.rathod@uic.com" ,
  "firstName": " Ramesh " ,
  "lastName": " Rathod " ,
  "phone": " +1 (189) 234-1122 x11-1275 "
  }
  "candidate":{
  "email": "srujan.rao@gmail.com" ,
  "firstName": " srujan " ,
  "lastName": " rao "
  }
  }
  ]
  }
```

I have tried writing schema to get the json output format as above, But i am not getting json output in the required format where the top part ( {"checkups":[{ ) is missing and closing brackets at the last bottom part ( }}]} ) is missing.

I have tried in different ways, but seems nothing is working out.

following is my xml output which needs to be transformed to json format with xsd schema.

```
  <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/RPT_Checkster_Outbound">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Checkupid>20</wd:Checkupid>
  <wd:JobTitle>Busisness Analyst, Project Management</wd:JobTitle>
  <wd:ReqID>F834234</wd:ReqID>
  <wd:Recruiter>
  <wd:InitEmail wd:Descriptor="ramesh.rathod@uic.com"></wd:InitEmail>
  <wd:p.InitFirstName>Ramesh</wd:p.InitFirstName>
  <wd:p.InitLastName>Rathod</wd:p.InitLastName>
  <wd:p.Phone wd:Descriptor="+1 (189) 234-1122 x11-1275">
  <wd:ID wd:type="WID">38fea2b75a77010c76933e693e57d3eb</wd:ID>
  </wd:p.Phone>
  </wd:Recruiter>
  <wd:Active_Candidates>
  <wd:CandEmail>srujan.rao@gmail.com</wd:CandEmail>
  <wd:p.FirstName>srujan</wd:p.FirstName>
  <wd:p.LastName>rao</wd:p.LastName>
  </wd:Active_Candidates>
```

Though subaccount attribute is not there in my xml, is there anyway that we can get it in output as specified in above sample json format ??

I know xsd schema at intermediate level but i am not good expert in xsd schema,Hence i would need help from experts on xsd schema to get the output in the required and above specified json format.

Would highly appreciate inputs on this.

Let me know for any additional information if needed on this.

Thanks,
Jithendra.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think XSD Schema would help with this problem. There might be some schema processors that include tools for XML-to-JSON conversion, but that's not part of what it means to be a schema processor.

There are quite a few libraries for XML-to-JSON conversion, and they vary a lot in how much control they give you over the output format (there are as many different ways of converting XML to JSON as there are tools - they will all produce different output).

Because your input and output aren't very closely related (for example `wd:p.InitFirstName` needs to become `firstName`), I would recommend XSLT for this job. You could either use XSLT 1 or 2 and generate the JSON output manually, or you could take advantage of the built-in JSON output serialization that comes with XSLT 3.0.

In XSLT 3.0 I would do it in two phases. First a regular XML-to-XML transformation that converts your input to something like this:

```
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
  <array key="checkups">
    <map>
       <string key="checkupId">20</string>
       <string key="jobTitle">Busisness Analyst, Project Management</string>
       <string key="requisitionNumber">F834234</string>
       <map key="subAccount">
         <string key="email">ramesh.rathod@uic.com</string>
etc
```

and then call the `xml-to-json()` function to convert this to JSON.

The first phase can be done with a set of template rules such as:

```
<xsl:template match="wd:p.InitFirstName">
  <string key="firstName">{.}</string>
</xsl:template>
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="wd:subAccount">
  <map key="subAccount">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </map>
</xsl:template>
```